# What is throwing IOException here?

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, exception, ioexception

I am trying to take data from a GUI and also from arraylists in my model class and then want to put them into another arraylist. Everytime the code runs, it works fine but then when I close the application and the serializer code runs the IOException gets thrown.

The only thing I access from the model class is an arraylist but I am accessing this array list in other classes and I don't have a problem.

Orginally I had the arraylist that I am adding to in the model class, I assumed that was what was throwing the exception so I moved it to another class, however the exception is still being thrown.

I have tried the rest of the event handlers on the form but this is the only one that causes the exception.

Here is the code that is causing the exception to occur:

```
private void btnRequestAppointmentActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    ArrayList<IAccountStrategy> observers;
    observers = model.getObservers();

    IAccountStrategy xx;

    xx = observers.get(accountIndex);     

    ArrayList<Appointments> appointment;
    appointment = xx.getAppointments();     
    Appointments app = new Appointments();

    setAppointmentDates(appointment, app);
    setAppointmentPatient(appointment, app);               
    xx.getAppointments().add(app);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Appointment Requested. A Secretary will check the request shortly");
}
```

And the classes that it is calling:

```
 public void setAppointmentDates(ArrayList<Appointments> appointment, Appointments app){
    String doctorsName = null;
    String sDate;
    Date appointmentDate = null;
    Date formattedDate = null;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    try{
    doctorsName = cboDoctor.getSelectedItem().toString();
    sDate = cboDate.getSelectedItem().toString();

    appointmentDate = sdf.parse(sDate);
    formattedDate = sdf.parse(sdf.format(appointmentDate));
    }
    catch(ParseException ex){
        System.out.println("ParseException has been caught");
    }

    app.setAppointmentDate(appointmentDate);
    app.setPreferredDoctor(doctorsName);
}           

 public void setAppointmentPatient(ArrayList<Appointments> appointment, Appointments app){
    ArrayList<IAccountStrategy> observers;
    observers = model.getObservers();

    IAccountStrategy xx;        
    xx = observers.get(accountIndex);

    app.setPatientID(xx.getAccountID());
    app.setPatientName(xx.getFirstname() +" "+ xx.getLastname());
    app.setPatientAge(xx.getAge());
    app.setPatientSex(xx.getSex());
}
```

This is the code for my serialization, it works on all my other classes:

```
   private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   
    String filename = "accounts.txt";

    try{
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);

    out.writeObject(model);

    out.close();
    file.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("IOException has been caught");
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: patientmanagementsystemv2.items.Appointments
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at patientmanagementsystemv2.gui.PatientHomePage.formWindowClosing(PatientHomePage.java:294)
    at patientmanagementsystemv2.gui.PatientHomePage.access$000(PatientHomePage.java:28)
    at patientmanagementsystemv2.gui.PatientHomePage$1.windowClosing(PatientHomePage.java:133)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Window.java:2054)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(JFrame.java:305)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2013)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I'm trying to get this program completed for tonight but I've been trying to fix this for hours. Any help is apprieciated.

Comment: check the stacktrace, it'll tell you  exactly what line threw it

Comment: How do I do this in Netbeans? I can't seem to find it anywhere

Comment: please paste the stack trace here! it has the info pertaining to the line that threw exception.

Comment: @TopLit check the console/output window

Comment: @TopLit check the console

Comment: Change your code from eg. `System.out.println("IOException has been caught");` to `ex.printStackTrace()`. Or you could use a breakpoint, if you know how to use the debugger.

Comment: Thanks im getting it now

Comment: Edited with the stack trace

Comment: It seems like PatientHomePage.java:294 is where you got the the error.

Comment: Thats the out.writeObject(model); statement. I'm not modifying the model though, so I don't understand the problem with it

Comment: Found out that the piece of code that is causing the problem is the statement:

 xx.getAppointments().add(app);

Answer (score 2):

## Stacktrace

Like [@Stultuske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636929/stultuske) mention in the comments, you can find the reason inside the stacktrace

### Finding Strategy

Lookup the first entry with the naming of your package. In your case look for `patientmanagementsystemv2.gui`

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: patientmanagementsystemv2.items.Appointments
    ...
    at patientmanagementsystemv2.gui.PatientHomePage.formWindowClosing(PatientHomePage.java:294)
    at patientmanagementsystemv2.gui.PatientHomePage.access$000(PatientHomePage.java:28)
    at patientmanagementsystemv2.gui.PatientHomePage$1.windowClosing(PatientHomePage.java:133)
    ...
```

At the top of your stacktrace you can see that you have a `NotSerializableException` at `patientmanagementsystemv2.gui.PatientHomePage.formWindowClosing(PatientHomePage.java:294`.

## The Problem

> `java.io.NotSerializableException: patientmanagementsystemv2.items.Appointments`

The reference type `Appointments` seems not to implement `Serializable` and the error raises because you try to serialize in the method `formWindowClosing` with `out.writeObject(model)` an instance of `Appointments`.

## Modify `Appointments`

If you own the class just write

```
public class Appointments implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

## But you expected an `IOException`

With `catch(IOException ex)` you catch an `IOException` and all subclasses of it including `NotSerializableException`.